# Jagged Array Initialization and Assignment

Tags: c#, arrays, textbox

Working on a "Find the Island" game program.  Will read in the number of rows and columns from the user and create a game map for play, using a char[][] array.  Problem is, while it compiles and assigns the first character with no problem, after that I get an IndexOutOfRange exception and have to terminate the program.  The code snippet is posted below, with the offending line marked.  How do I fix this?

```
 char[][] Waves = new char[Rows + 1][];

        for (int counter = 0; counter < Rows+1; counter++)
            Waves[counter] = new char[Columns];

        MapRows = Rows;
        MapCols = Columns;

        for (int c = 0; c < Rows; c++)
        {
            for (int d = 0; d < Columns; d++)
            {
                if (c == 0 && d == 0)
                    Waves[c][d] = 'X';
                else if (c == 0)
                    Waves[c][d] = (char)d;  // Offending line here
                else if (d == 0)
                    Waves[c][d] = (char)c;
                else
                    Waves[c][d] = '~';
            }            
        }
```

The map should appear as follows for a 3x3 map (spaces and line breaks will be added when printing):

```
X123
1~~~
2~~~
3~~~
```

Second, and much less important, I plan on printing the map to a read-only text box.  How do I write it to the text box where I print a row of characters from the array, before ending that line and printing the next row of characters?  The for loops are easy, getting it to print is not.

Comment: Look at your first 3 lines. You're confusing rows and columns.

Comment: No, not really.  This way if columns and rows are different ints, there will be x row char arrays with y columns in each array.

EDIT: Found what you actually meant there, rather than the obvious.  Fixed.

Comment: Set Columns to 10 and Rows to 20, I think you'll see what I mean.

Comment: You should not change your question to fix it. In this way the answers given become meaningless.

Comment: My mistake.  I don't use SO often.  Won't happen again.

Comment: What input are you getting an exception for? I don't get an exception when I run your code as posted.